# Is there a universal property for the ultraproduct?

Tags: category-theory, model-theory, nonstandard-analysis

Given an ultrafilter U on a set I and a collection of ser X_i ($I \in I$) one defines the ultraproduct as the quotient of $\prod X_i $ by the identification $x_i=y_i :\leftrightarrow \{i:x_i=y_i\} \in U$. Is there a possibilityto give this definition in a categorical way by referring to a universal property of a category?

Comment: This isn't really my cup of tea but I recall something along the following lines.  Don't take this too seriously as the words might be out of order, but somehow the right words are as follows: the ultrapower can be obtained by quotienting the Stone-Cech compactification (which is generally thought of as being "categorical"), in such a way that a natural topology thereon becomes Hausdorff.  If this is really important, I can try to look this up in a more serious fashion.

Comment: I think something like this question was asked before, and the answer was something like "use the $X_i$ to construct a sheaf over $\beta I$, and then the ultrapower arises as the stalk of this sheaf at a point given by a non-principal ultrafilter."

Comment: Note that every quotient has a universal property for general reasons (quotients by an equivalence relation are coequalizers).

Comment: I recall a question on MO. It's a colimit over a certain diagram derived from the filter.

Comment: Ah, here's the MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11261/is-the-ultraproduct-concept-fundamentally-category-theoretic

Comment: Actually, I was thinking about [this one](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105397/there-are-two-slightly-different-notions-of-ultraproduct-why-is-one-said-to-be), but I wasn't able to find it just now.

Comment: @ZhenLin : This pretty much answers my question. Could you copy that definition from MO and post it as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be the ultrafilter $U$ considered as a partially ordered set in its own right, and consider the diagram of shape $\mathcal{U}^\mathrm{op}$ where the value at an element $S$ is the product $\prod_{i \in S} X_i$ and the transition maps are the obvious projections. The colimit of this diagram (which is a directed system!) is then the ultraproduct $\left( \prod_{i \in I} X_i \right) / U$.